# display all the Prime numbers which are less than certain number

Tags: c++

I've been learning C++ for few weeks, however, I got stuck, I have a function isPrime(), works great to show if the number is prime or no,  I need to display all the Prime numbers which are less than 200. But it's not working see line marked with comment

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Function Prototypes
bool isPrime(int);

int main()
{
    int Num;

        cout << "This program let you know if the number entered is a "
             << "prime number.\nEnter a number: ";
        cin  >> Num;

    cout << "The number " << Num;

    if (isPrime(Num))
    {
        cout << " is a Prime number." << endl;
    }
    else
        cout << " is not a Prime number." << endl;

    return 0;
}

//isPrime
bool isPrime(int Num)
{
    if (Num > 1)
    {
        for (int i = 2; i <= Num; ++i)
        {

            if (Num % i == 0)
            {
                if(Num == i)
                    return true;
                else if 
                           for(int n = 2; n < 200; n++) { // HERE
                  // isPrime will be true for prime numbers
                         isPrime = isPrimeNumber(n);

                            if(isPrime == true)
                                       cout<<n<<" ";
                           }
                              return 0;
                              else
                    return false;
            }

        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: It is unclear what you're trying to do.
1. If the purpose of `isPrime(n)` is to check if n is prime, then you should write a separate function to list all primes less than a certain number.
2. What is `isPrimeNumber(n)`? This function isn't defined here.

Comment: Your attempt to assign a value to the function name is reminiscent of Pascal. If that is where you are coming from, forget that practice when using C++.

Comment: As for the quality of the question itself, "it's not working" is a useless problem description. Imagine the next person with your problem searching SO for "it's not working" to see if someone (you) had asked the question already. Think about how many irrelevant questions that person would have to wade through, since *every* debugging question comes down to "it's not working". Try describing what is not working. What have you observed? What are the symptoms? If it's a compilation error, what is the error message (copied as text into your question)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You added the loop in the wrong place. That function is only for checking a particular number. Either you would need to make another function to print all the prime numbers which are less than 200 or you can directly add the loop in the main() function, like i did.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Function Prototypes
bool isPrime(int);

int main()
{
    int Num;

        cout << "This program let you know if the number entered is a "
             << "prime number.\nEnter a number: ";
        cin  >> Num;

    cout << "The number " << Num;


    // Check numbers here
    for(int n = 2; n < 200; n++) {

        if (isPrime(n)){
            cout << n << " is a Prime number." << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

//isPrime - This is your original isPrime Code
bool isPrime(int Num)
{
    if (Num > 1)
    {
        for (int i = 2; i <= Num; ++i)
        {

            if (Num % i == 0)
            {
                if(Num == i)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }

        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers rarely explain anything. A good answer should begin with text explaining the answer. Code can follow the explanation. (This is very similar to how a good question should begin with text stating the question, potentially followed by code illustrating the question.)

Comment: @JaMiT I added comments in the code.. I think the OP will understand it already as there not much changes, but if you say so.. I will.

Comment: @bhpcv I truly want to thank you for helping me, I understood what you said and your code, the problem was with the loop, Don't listen to what all the haters say in here. Unfortunately, many people have a fixed mindset they will always give down vote for no resean. Again thanks that helped me understand it!

Comment: @JohnJoryJr I find your comment insulting, Not only did I have a reason for voting down this answer, I stated that reason in a comment.

Comment: @bhpcv The change is helpful, thanks. Keep in mind that you are answering not just for the OP, but also for the next person with the same question, someone who is less likely to spot a subtle change to the code when it is not explicitly called out as "this is what changed".